# C# WPF Sum datagrid column to label

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am having problems adding up all of the values in a WPF Datagrid column to a label upon a change event (probably SelectionChanged).  I have this code:

```
private void tblData_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
        decimal total = 0;

        foreach(DataRowView rowView in (DataView)this.tblData.ItemsSource)
        {
            total += (decimal)rowView["Total"];
        }
        lblTotal.Content = total.ToString();
}
```

But it breaks my program, it throws a 'System.InvalidCastException'.  Can anyone please look at my code and help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `rowView["Total"]` exactly? It is an `object`, right?

Comment: where does the code throws this exception? you have two casts in your code.

Comment: @JensHorstmann - I'm sorry, I'm very noob in programming, even though I took this career in college I have never since applied it.  What do you mean by two casts?  I am trying to update a label based on the sum of all the values in the column "total" in real time.  My WPF DataGrid is static, meaning that I declared the columns and their name in XAML

Comment: @SonerGönül - I am assigning the name of the column to the rowView

Comment: @JensHorstmann - The code throws the exception at the "foreach" specifically at (DataView)this.tblData.ItemsSource).